# Calling a javascript function infinitly on click of a button?

Tags: javascript, html

Okay so this is a bit of a weird request. So I've programmed tiles that generate using JavaScript (with the help of people here on stack overflow) now I would like to make it so that on the click of a button my changecolors function is called a set number of times so that the colors of the tiles randomly change before your eyes. I've got a button that every time you click it the colors change, but how can I make it so on that click they continuously change? I've tried using the JavaScript function set Interval(function, time) and couldn't seem to get it to work. Just in case, I will also inform you that I am putting a button in that will also stop the random color changes.. Here's the code. Any help would be great!!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<style>
.cell {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1px;
  padding:4px;
}
button{
float:left;
padding:4px;
}
</style>


<title></title>
<head><script type="text/javascript">
function generateGrid(){
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (b = 0; b < 5; b++) { 
      div = document.createElement("div");
      div.id = "box" + i +""+ b;
      div.className = "cell";
      document.body.appendChild(div);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  }
}
function changeColors(){
for(i =0;i < 5; i++){
    for (b=0;b<5;b++){
        var holder=document.createElement("div");
        holder=document.getElementById("box" + i +""+ b);
        holder.style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();

    }
}

}
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}
</script>
</head>


<body>
<script>

generateGrid();

changeColors();


</script>
<button onclick="changeColors();">Click me to change colors</button>
<button onclick="window.setInterval(changeColors(),2000);">Click me to start cycle</button>
</body>





</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setTimeoutFunction was not sintatically correct

```js
var stop = false;

function generateGrid(){
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (b = 0; b < 5; b++) { 
      div = document.createElement("div");
      div.id = "box" + i +""+ b;
      div.className = "cell";
      document.body.appendChild(div);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  }
}
function changeColors(){
for(i =0;i < 5; i++){
    for (b=0;b<5;b++){
        var holder=document.createElement("div");
        holder=document.getElementById("box" + i +""+ b);
        holder.style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();

    }
}

}
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    generateGrid();

    changeColors();
});
```

```css
.cell {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1px;
  padding:4px;
}
button{
float:left;
padding:4px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>



<title></title>



<body>

<button onclick="changeColors();">Click me to change colors</button>
<button onclick="window.setInterval(function(){changeColors();},2000);">Click me to start cycle</button>
</body>





</html>
```

**Edited to work without jQuery**

Comment: This is exactly what I want.. but is there a way to do it without jQuery ? I'm technically not supposed to use that or I would've done that.. But if there isn't a way I can make do with JQuery :D

Comment: Edited to work without jQuery. If the answer works for you, please accept it as the answer of the question

Answer (score 0):

Your `changeColors()` should have been `changeColors` for `window.setInterval`.

I cleaned up your code and added the stop/start buttons. By creating an array of elements, it saves the changeColors function having to locate each element every iteration. Lastly I changed your generateGrid function to accept a width and height. A bit overkill but I got carried away :)

HTML

```
<button onclick="changeColors();">Click me to change colors</button>
<button onclick="startCycle();">Start cycle</button>
<button onclick="stopCycle();">Stop cycle</button>
<br>
<br>
```

JavaScript

```
var elements = [];
function generateGrid(width, height) {
    for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.id = "box" + y + "" + x;
            div.className = "cell";
            document.body.appendChild(div);
            elements.push(div);
        }
        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }
}

function changeColors() {
    for (e in elements) {
        elements[e].style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
    }
}

function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

var interval = null;
function startCycle() {
    if (interval) return;
    interval = window.setInterval(changeColors, 500);
}

function stopCycle() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = null;
}

generateGrid(3, 5);
changeColors();
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/GrahamWalters/7sjbvgfp/2/)

Comment: Kinda fun when you click on `startCycle` a bunch of times!

Comment: This is great, thanks for the help. You did a little extra with adding the stop button for me but its okay ;)

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Don't forget to up vote/accept the answer

Comment: Quick question about the code, can you explain to me how you programmed the start/stop cycle? I'm confused at the whole interval thing. It works I just wanna better understand it

Comment: Sure. First we declare an `interval` variable. Then when we call `setInterval`  we pass it the reference to the function `changeColors`. `setInterval` returns an id which we assign to `interval`. For `stopCycle` we pass the `interval` (the id) to `clearInterval`. Finally we reset the `interval` to `null`.

Comment: @lionetti12345 the following link has another example:  [Example 2: Alternating two colors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval#Example_2_Alternating_two_colors)

Answer (score 0):

Simple Just added one function on Click of button try this:

```html
<style>
.cell {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1px;
  padding:4px;
}
button{
float:left;
padding:4px;
}
</style>


<title></title>
<head><script type="text/javascript">
function generateGrid(){
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (b = 0; b < 5; b++) { 
      div = document.createElement("div");
      div.id = "box" + i +""+ b;
      div.className = "cell";
      document.body.appendChild(div);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  }
}
function changeColors(){
for(i =0;i < 5; i++){
    for (b=0;b<5;b++){
       // var holder=document.createElement("div");
       var holder=document.getElementById("box" + i +""+ b);
        holder.style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();

    }
}

}
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}
</script>
</head>


<body>
<script>

generateGrid();
changeColors();
function animate1()
  {
    setInterval(function(){
      changeColors();
    },5000);
  }

</script>
<button onclick="changeColors();">Click me to change colors</button>
<button onclick="animate1();">Click me to start cycle</button>
</body>
```

Note: setTimeout function gets called only once after your set duration where setTimeout gets called indefinite unless you use clearInterval() to Stop it.